# Google Sheets Run Script For All Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got the following script and it works fine, except I seem to have to modify the sheet (every month) for it to work.  Is there a way I can just have it run this script for all the tabs in my Spreadsheet automatically?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (sheetName === 'Nov. 2021' && //only do the current sheet!
      range.getRow() > 1 && 
      range.getColumn() == 6 && 
      typeof value === 'string') {
    if(!range.getFormula()) {
      range.setValue(value.toUpperCase());
    } else {
      if(range.getFormula().substring(0,6).toUpperCase() == '=UPPER') {
        return;
      } else {
        range.setFormula('=UPPER(' + range.getFormula().substring(1) + ')');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just remove the if( sheetname = term. If you are allowing other users to work on the spreadsheet I suspect you will run into problems that may require you to use lock Service and go to an installable trigger.

Comment: It's just me using this sheet, it's not shared.  I can't seem to get it to work, can you provide an example so I know what to remove?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.getFormula().subString(0, 6).toUpperCase() != '=UPPER') {
    e.range.setFormula('=UPPER(' + range.getFormula().substring(1) + ')');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  My code is below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 6 && typeof value === 'string') {
    if(!range.getFormula()) {
      range.setValue(value.toUpperCase());
    } else {
      if(range.getFormula().substring(0,6).toUpperCase() == '=UPPER') {
        return;
      } else {
        range.setFormula('=UPPER(' + range.getFormula().substring(1) + ')');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction.